# angular-slickgrid build failed

Tags: angular, webpack, slickgrid, terser

after importing Angular slick grid, angular build fails

```
import { AngularSlickgridModule } from 'angular-slickgrid';

imports:[AngularSlickgridModule]
```

ng build --prod

[image: Error]

Answer (score 2):

From the angular-slickgrid github example, the correct way to import AngularSlickgridModule is as below

```
import { AngularSlickgridModule } from 'angular-slickgrid';

imports: [
AppRoutingRoutingModule,
BrowserModule,
FormsModule,
HttpClientModule,
NgSelectModule,
TabsModule.forRoot(),
TranslateModule.forRoot({
  loader: {
    provide: TranslateLoader,
    useFactory: (createTranslateLoader),
    deps: [HttpClient]
  }
}),
AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot({
  // add any Global Grid Options/Config you might want
  // to avoid passing the same options over and over in each grids of your App
  enableAutoResize: true,
  autoResize: {
    containerId: 'demo-container',
    sidePadding: 15
  }
}),],
```

For more details refer the sample codes in this [repo](https://github.com/ghiscoding/angular-slickgrid-demos)

Comment: I have imported it correctly. tell me if you find any other issue

Comment: You've shared only the import statements. Share more code to analyze further. Have you tried "ng serve" command. It can provide more useful error information.

Comment: i have attached an image of error. can't you help with that error ?

Comment: he's missing the `forRoot()` in the import of `AngularSlickgridModule.forRoot()`, it won't work without it period, I know since I'm the author and I already told him on GitHub to look at that `forRoot()`... I provided plenty of Wikis and Demos and cloning the Demo is definitely the easiest way to get started... BTW TranslateService is no longer a dependency, it could be used with or without, it's an @Optional service, so it could be ommited from the imports.

Comment: I have also tried with forRoot(). this only happens when i build in production mode. BTW @ghiscoding sorry to bother you. i think this is problem while minifying the bundle for es2015.js

Comment: Sorry but I told you like 10 times in GitHub, clone the demo and base yourself from that, it works from there!!! Again I will repeat, I use the demo to run an Angular production build every single time I release a version. Also, just showing a print of an error is not a valid SO question, there's just not enough info for anyone to help you.

Comment: and if you do a bit of research you'll find things like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/13096)